# Erro no valor da variável

Tags: php, float

Estou com a seguinte dúvida, tenho que somar um conjunto de valores que estão setados como `string's`, então tive que converter para `float`, utilizei a funcao `str_replace()`, só que ao testar a variável com o `var_dump` e realizar a soma em uma função que percorre um `array` com os objetos das variáveis,  notei que o valor original, no caso R$4.200,00, foi convertido para (4,2) literalmente.

Como consigo resolver esse problema? Porque eu preciso somar o valor de 4.200,00. A saída na web ficou a seguinte :

> 1 Mouse ótico Microsoft R$ 89,90 Perifericos
>   2 Impressora HP Laser 1320 R$ 850,00 Impressoras
>   3 Macbook Pro Apple R$ 4.200,00 Notebooks
>   4 Teclado sem fio Genius R$ 110,00 Perifericos
>   5 Computador Lenovo R$ 2.100,00 Computadores
>
> 89.90float(89.9)
>   850.00float(850)
>   **4.200.00float(4.2) <- Reparem aqui**

O script é esse da classe `Produto`:

```
<?php

class Produto {
 public $nome;
 private $codigo;
 private $valor;
 private $categoria;

 function __construct($nome,$codigo,$categoria,$valor){

     $this->nome=$nome;
     $this->categoria = $categoria;
     $this->codigo=$codigo;
     $this->valor=$valor;

 }

 function __toString(){

     return $this->codigo."&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp".
            $this->nome."&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp".
            $this->valor."&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp".
            $this->categoria->getNome()."&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp";

 }

 function getValor(){
     return $this->valor;
 }

 function calcularPreco($arrayProduto){
     $somaTotal=0;
     for($i=0;$i<=sizeof($arrayProduto)-1;$i++){

        $objProd=$arrayProduto[$i];

        $charRemove= Array("R","$",",");
        $charSub= Array("","",".");
        $novoValor= str_replace($charRemove,$charSub,$objProd->getValor());

        $somaTotal= $somaTotal += $novoValor; 
        echo $somaTotal."</br> R";
        echo $i."</br>";

            if($i==sizeof($arrayProduto)){
                $somaMedia=$somaTotal/$i;
            }else{
                echo $i."</br>";
            }

    }


 }
}
?>
```

E o script da classe que instancia o objeto `Produto`:

```
<?php

    include "Categoria.class.php";
    include "Produto.class.php";
    // Instancia dos objetos de categoria.

    $cat1=new Categoria("Perifericos",1);
    $cat2=new Categoria("Notebooks",2);
    $cat3=new Categoria("Computadores",3);
    $cat4=new Categoria("Impressoras",4);

    //Array que guarda referencias de objetos categoria.
    $categoriaList= Array($cat1,$cat2,$cat3,$cat4);

    //Instnacia dos objetos produto.
    $prod1=new Produto("Mouse ótico Microsoft",1,$cat1,"R$ 89,90");
    $prod2=new Produto("Impressora HP Laser 1320",2,$cat4,"R$ 850,00");
    $prod3=new Produto("Macbook Pro Apple",3,$cat2,"R$ 4.200,00");
    $prod4=new Produto("Teclado sem fio Genius",4,$cat1,"R$ 110,00");
    $prod5=new Produto("Computador Lenovo",5,$cat3,"R$ 2.100,00");

    //Array que guarda referencias de objetos produto.
    $prodList= Array($prod1,$prod2,$prod3,$prod4,$prod5);

    //Percorrendo Array de categoria.
for($i=0;$i<=sizeof($categoriaList)-1;$i++){

    echo $categoriaList[$i]."</br>";

}


    //Percorrendo Array de produto.

for($i=0;$i<=sizeof($prodList)-1;$i++){

    echo $prodList[$i]."</br>";


}   

$objProd=$prodList[0];

$charRemove= Array("R","$",",");
$charSub= Array("","",".");
$novoValor= str_replace($charRemove,$charSub,$objProd->getValor());


echo $novoValor;

$doubString= (float) $novoValor;
var_dump($doubString);

echo "</br></br>";

$objProd=$prodList[1];

$charRemove= Array("R","$",",");
$charSub= Array("","",".");
$novoValor= str_replace($charRemove,$charSub,$objProd->getValor());


echo $novoValor;

$doubString= (float) $novoValor;
var_dump($doubString);

echo "</br></br>";

$objProd=$prodList[2];

$charRemove= Array("R","$",",");
$charSub= Array("","",".");
$novoValor= str_replace($charRemove,$charSub,$objProd->getValor());


echo $novoValor;

$doubString= (float) $novoValor;
var_dump($doubString);

echo "</br></br>";

//$prod1->calcularPreco($prodList);

?>
```

Comment: Tens algum maneira de mostrar o código a funcionar. Tipo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema está no formato. Um valor `float` tem sua parte decimal separada por ponto e a parte milhar não possui separação.

Seu valor é `4.200,00`. Você troca vírgula por ponto ficando `4.200.00`. Visto que há um ponto entre 4 e 2 (milhar), a linguagem vê isso como se fosse a parte decimal, simplificando para `4.2`.

Portanto você deve substituir ponto por vazio e depois vírgula por ponto:

```
$charRemove = array("R", "$", ".", ",");
$charSub = array("", "", "", ".");
```

Comment: Cara mas existe outra forma?  No Java eu uso duble :(

Comment: Acredito que não